# Three Altitudes of a triangle are concurrent

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I have been told that this well known fact can be shown using only Euclid's propositions from books one to three, and cyclic quadrilaterals.

I can't figure out how to start, which quadrilateral should I have in consideration. Also the only proposition about cyclic quadrilaterals is 3.22, which I am not sure how to use.

[image]
Edit: I think I have made some progress. Let CE and AF be altitudes from C and A, the idea is to show that the line going through B and D is perpendicular to AC. Which could be done by 3.22 if either AGDE or GCFD were cyclic quadrilaterals. I don't know how to show this last part.

Comment: I think you mean AF and GCFD instead of AE and GCED. (The F looks like it could be an E in the diagram.)

Comment: This doesn't help you, but you could do this just using formulas if you were allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $AEFC$ is cyclic, $\angle FEB =\angle ACB$.

Since $BEDF$ is cyclic, $\angle FEB=\angle BDF$.

Thus $\angle GDF+\angle ACB=180^\circ$.

Comment: The problem I find is to show that the quadrilaterals are cyclic from Euclid's books, since it does not seem to be any proposition about it.

Comment: In this case, it's fairly easy: $A$, $E$, $F$, $C$ all lie on the circle with diameter $AC$, while $B$, $E$, $D$, $F$ lie on the circle with diameter $BD$. In general, you can check whether the two opposite angles add up to $180^\circ$ (like in $BEDF$) or the two diagonal-side angles looking at a side are equal (like in $AEFC$.

Comment: Two things: first I think $\angle BDE$ should read $\angle BDF$ in line 2.

Comment: Also, one way to justify that $AEFC$ is cyclic is to prove the converse of Prop 31 which says the angle in the semicircle is right. Show that a right angle standing on a straight line has its vertex fall on the semicircle described on that straight line as a diameter. In your diagram, we notice that $\angle AEC$ and $\angle AFC$ are right by construction. This would be sufficient to show that $AEFC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Answer (score 2):

Expanded answer:

[image]

Take the diagram as shown, with $AF \perp BC$ and $CE \perp AB$ but consider the point $G$ to be merely the extension of $BD$ to meet $AC$ - angle unknown.

Now we find that $E$ and $F$ are points on the circle with $AC$ as diameter, giving $AEFC$ as cyclic, so we can see that the [inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) from chord $AF$ means that the internal angle $\angle ACF=\angle FEB$, the external angle at $E$.

Similarly  $E$ and $F$ are points on the circle with $BD$ as diameter, giving $DEBF$ cyclic and the inscribed angle from chord $BF$ gives $\angle FEB=\angle FDB$.

Then since $\angle ACF=\angle FDB$ we have that $\angle ACF+\angle FDG = 180^\circ$ and completing the angles in quadrilateral $GDFC$ we see that $\angle CGD = 90^\circ$ and $BG$ is the third altitude.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of showing the altitudes of $ABC$ are concurrent is (1)Prove the right bisectors of a triangle are concurrent. (2) Draw line $l_A$ thru $A$ parallel to $BC$, line $l_B$ thru $B$ parallel to $CA,$ and $l_C$ thru $C$ parallel to $AB.$ These lines meet pair-wise at points $A',B',C'.$ The altitudes of $ABC$ are the right bisectors of $A'B'C'.$

Comment: There is a lot to argument there. I am trying to do a step by step proof with explicit mention of the propositions used on each step. Also would like to follow the cyclic quadrilaterals path.